# VBA function applied on FILTER function in Excel gives #VALUE! result

Tags: excel, vba, filter

I have a VBA function which takes a range as a parameter and that I use in excel on timeseries, which works fine.

```
Function func(r As Range)
    ...
End Function
```

I wanted to run this function on filtered values (only 2006 for example) those so I did :

```
=func(FILTER(I1:I4631;MAP(H1:H4631;LAMBDA(a;YEAR(a)=2006))))
```

However that gives me a #VALUE! result...

When I run the VBA debugger, the function isn't even launched.

I noticed I can do

```
=FILTER(I1:I4631;MAP(H1:H4631;LAMBDA(a;YEAR(a)=2006)))
```

in one cell (T3 in this example) and then use my function func on the resulted range (spilled) and that works.

```
=func(T3#)
```

But I would like to avoid this step and do the thing in one formula

I use Microsoft® Excel® for Microsoft 365 MSO.

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong, and maybe how to correct this ?
Thank you !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this for example:

```
Function func(r As Variant)
    Dim el As Variant
    Debug.Print "r is of type " & TypeName(r)
    For Each el In r
        Debug.Print "...Item", TypeName(el)
    Next el
End Function
```

`FILTER()` is giving you a variant array of values, not a `Range`

My test:
[image]

Immediate pane output:

```txt
r is of type Variant()
...Item       String
...Item       String
```

Comment: I don't know why it still doesn't work.
I tried to run the debugger but the breakpoints aren't even reached as if the function was not run.

Comment: See updates above for my test and output.

Comment: Thank you Tim.
It appears I can't (don't know how to) see the debug prints.
I replaced them by Msgbox and I have the output so that means that the function is correctly executed. Now I have to figure out why my program doesn't stop at breakpoint !

Comment: Ctrl+G in the VB editor will show the Immediate pane - that's where any `Debug.Print` output appears.

Comment: Thanks, I can see the prints. Can't still debug but I will look at this tomorrow now.

Comment: If ever someone has the same issue as me, the second problem came from the fact that my function was crashing without an error message. The crashes came from the fact that I was still using Range methods (r.Cells.Count or r(i)). I replaced those by Ubound(r) and r(i,1) and it works now.
Thanks again @Tim Williams !